# How to automatically create sections and bookmarks in PDF by text or mask?

Tags: pdf, latex, pdf-generation, pdflatex

By "text or mask" i mean something like "Chapter ?: *\n" which will result in bookmarks as "Chapter 1: Hello world", "Chapter 2: Lorem Ipsum", etc. The titles are already in the .pdf as text boxes.

Comment: So you have an existing/already-made PDF that you want to add bookmarks to... automatically?

Comment: Yes. I can do it manually, but it will take too long. My doc is about 300 pages. But I know how all titles are composed.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341086/49683 by @Werner may help? :)